# My JavaScript file will run from one html file, but not from another in the same directory

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

Both friends.html and homepage.html are in the same folder. Homepage can access friends.js just fine but when I try to access it from friends.html it gives me this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/static/js/friends.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

friends.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/friends.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-wrapper">
        <div class="friend_request">
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <script src="../../static/js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/friends.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

homepage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/spinner.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/mainpage.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/background.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/output.css' %}">
    
    {% if newuser %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/instructions.css' %}">
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <a href="{% url 'friends' %}">
        <button class="title-btn fade-in" id="friends-btn" onclick="friends_tab()">Friends >></button>
    </a>


    <!-- django to js variables -->
    <script data-newuser="{{ newuser }}">
        window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}"; 
        const data = document.currentScript.dataset;
        const isNewUser = data.newuser == 'True';
    </script>

    <script src="../../static/js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/mainpage.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/friends.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@login_required
def friends(request):
    return render(request, 'friends.html')
```

Comment: Why you are using static for your CSS Files but not for JS? Use static also for js like you did it with CSS and it will Work. Its because of the relative paths

Comment: @Christoph Not sure if its intended behavior but putting the load static tag at the top loads all static files for the page. I tried adding it to the bottom to double check and get the same error.

Comment: I mean script src, this should be same way as you did it with style a href like <script src="{% static 'js/friends'   %}">